# how to extract particular cell to my SQL in EXCEL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

Here is a example table in Excel:

```
ID Name  Account
1  Jon   001
2  Snow  002
3  Alive 003
```

I want to create a SQL according to account. It looks like,

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE WHERE ACCOUNT=' ';
```

Is it possible to make system could fulfill `ACCOUNT=' '`? Like system could input each value automatically.

It should like `WHERE ACCOUNT='C1', ACCOUNT='C2', ACCOUNT='C3'...`

Comment: Are you really using MySQL here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you copied your accounts into a range like `Range("E1:E10")`.
Then you can use a for loop to change accounts for every turn.
Change your Query as,

```
SQL_Query = "Select * From Customer_Table Where Account ="
```

then try a `For Loop`.

```
Dim Query as String
For i = 1 to 10
    Query = SQL_Query & Cells(i,4).value
    'Do your query here.
    'Be careful about that your results should be copied under the last row.
    'Otherwise only the last one will be shown.
Next
```